# Build an Excel Worksheet that lists information from another worksheet in an opposite format

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, unique

I have an Excel worksheet (TAB1) that lists items like this.

| Class | Type |
| --- | --- |
| AA | A |
| AB | B |
| AC | A |
| AD | C |

So, there are unique Class values, but the Type values may be associated with more than one Class.

I'm trying to build a second worksheet (TAB2) in the same workbook that lists the Type values and all of the Classes they are associated with.

| Type | Classes |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | AA | AC |
| B | AB |  |
| C | AD |  |

I'm able to build the Type column in the TAB2 worksheet by using the UNIQUE function like this.

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER('TAB1'!B:B,(TRIM('TAB1'!B:B)<>"Type")*(TRIM('TAB1'!B:B)<>""),"")))
```

But I haven't figured out a way to populate the "Classes" columns.  Is there a function or combination of functions that will list all of the "Class" values of each "Type" across the rows?

It would also be acceptable to list the Type values in row 1 across the columns and have the classes listed below the type values they are associated with.

I would appreciate any help that someone could provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using one of the following, both of the formulas works with `MS365` version of `Excel`.

Using <kbd>MAKEARRAY()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _type, 'TAB1'!B2:B5,
     _class, 'TAB1'!A2:A5,
     _uniqueType, UNIQUE(_type),
     _rows, ROWS(_uniqueType),
     _columns, MAX(COUNTIFS(_type,_type)),
     _listClasses, MAKEARRAY(_rows, _columns, LAMBDA(x,y,IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(_class, INDEX(_uniqueType,x)=_type),y),""))),
     HSTACK(_uniqueType, _listClasses))
```

---

Or, Using <kbd>REDUCE()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _type, 'TAB1'!B2:B5,
     _class, 'TAB1'!A2:A5,
     _uniqueType, UNIQUE(_type),
     _listClasses, IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("", _uniqueType, LAMBDA(x,y, VSTACK(x, TOROW(FILTER(_class, _type=y))))),1),""),
     HSTACK(_uniqueType, _listClasses))
```

---

Both of the above formulas uses `LAMBDA()` helper functions to iterate the cells and uses the functions to return one single dynamic array output however, if you want to return the data using fill down method then you could try

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(DROP(TOCOL('TAB1'!B:B,1),1)))
```

---

• And formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=TOROW(FILTER('TAB1'!$A$2:$A$5,'TAB2'!$A1='TAB1'!$B$2:$B$5))
```

---

The above formula needs to fill down!

---

One more alternative way, with the advent of <kbd>GROUPBY()</kbd> function in `MS365` version for Beta Users, one could use the following, convert the data into a `Structured References` aka `Tables`  as it automatically resizes to store more data, and as the formula references the `Table` it automatically gets updated when new data is added, use as below:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, GROUPBY(Table1[Type],Table1[Class],ARRAYTOTEXT,0,0),
     δ, TAKE(α,,-1),
     HSTACK(TAKE(α,,1),
     IFNA(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&δ,", ",SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(δ)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(δ,", ",))))),", "),"")))
```

---

File can be downloaded from here: **[Excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckWdqhY4aUz2GnZb5?e=7mYsq9)**

---

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: I used the first example you posted.  But it took me many hours to figure out what it is doing.  I was completely unfamiliar with the MAKEARRAY and LAMBDA functions.  I made one change to have SORT(UNIQUE(_type)) for the uniqueType variable, as my actual data is about 200 unique types and it was difficult to find anything.  My "TAB1" data was sorted in Class sequence, so the "TAB2" came out with the classes in the proper sequence.  Thank you for the help.  I do appreciate it.  One thing I couldn't figure out is the MAX(COUNTIFS(_type,_type)).  I don't understand what that is doing.

Comment: @Alan you can download the file from here, i have also added the file in the answers. **[Download](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckWdqhY4aUz2GnZb5?e=7mYsq9)**. So `MAX(COUNTIFS(_type,_type))` it gives the max number of times of types, which is used for columns .